# SQL INNER JOIN with DISTINCT rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
SELECT collections.title, collections.uniqueID, uploads.uniqueID as thumb 
FROM collections 
INNER JOIN uploads ON collections.uniqueID = uploads.uploadGroup 
WHERE collections.owner = @owner
```

in this instance if I have 3 rows in "uploads" that have the matching uniqueid/uploadgroup (as in 3 uploads in a collection) this gives me back 3 rows.

what I'm looking for is ONE row for each DISTINCT COLLECTIONS.UNIQUEID - is this possible?

so when collections has

```
1 | title | idhere
```

and uploads has

```
1 | uniqueID1 | idhere
2 | uniqueID2 | idhere
3 | uniqueID3 | idhere
```

I'm currently returning

```
1 | title | uniqueID1
2 | title | uniqueID2
3 | title | uniqueID3
```

when all I want to return is

```
1 | title | uniqueID1
```

Comment: Why `1 | title | uniqueID1` not `1 | title | uniqueID3` ? Any criteria for such decision? PS: you need to choose either `mysql` or `sql-server`. The solution would be vendor-specific

Comment: You either want to Group By title or take the Top 1 row.  You'll have to decide that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach (sql server only):

```
SELECT collections.title, collections.uniqueID, uploads.uniqueID as thumb 
FROM collections
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM uploads
    WHERE collections.uniqueID = uploads.uploadGroup
    ORDER BY uploads.uniqueID -- not required, can be changed to any column you want
) uploads
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need a simple distinct list from the uploads table then you can do it like this:

```
SELECT collections.title, collections.uniqueID, uploads.uniqueID as thumb 
FROM collections 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT uniqueID FROM uploads) uploads ON collections.uniqueID = uploads.uploadGroup 
WHERE collections.owner = @owner
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT collections.title, collections.uniqueID, min(uploads.uniqueID) as thumb 
FROM collections 
JOIN uploads ON collections.uniqueID = uploads.uploadGroup 
WHERE collections.owner = @owner
GROUP BY collections.title, collections.uniqueID
```